# Posting JSON to Rails 4

Tags: json, api, post, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having trouble posting to a JSON field (using postman) in my Ruby + Rails web app. I am confused as to what the controller permissions (strong params) need to be and the subsequent posting format.

I am trying to send in raw format using postman (Content-type is set to application/json)

```
{"recipe":{"recipe_id":"174a4839020d0820","Category":"Eaten"}, "Nuts":{...}, "Milk":{...}}
```

My controller looks like:

```
class OnboardingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_onboarding, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

  # GET /onboardings
  # GET /onboardings.json
  def index
    @onboardings = Onboarding.all
  end

  # GET /onboardings/1
  # GET /onboardings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /onboardings/new
  def new
    @onboarding = Onboarding.new
  end

  # GET /onboardings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /onboardings
  # POST /onboardings.json
  def create
    ap params
    @onboarding = Onboarding.new(onboarding_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @onboarding.save
        format.html { render :json => @onboarding.to_json , notice: 'Onboarding was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @onboarding }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @onboarding.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /onboardings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /onboardings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @onboarding.update(onboarding_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @onboarding, notice: 'Onboarding was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @onboarding }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @onboarding.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end

  # DELETE /onboardings/1
  # DELETE /onboardings/1.json
  def destroy
    @onboarding.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to onboardings_url, notice: 'Onboarding was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_onboarding
      @onboarding = Onboarding.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def onboarding_params
      params.require(:onboarding).permit(:recipe, :recipe_id, :category, `enter code here`:fruits, :nuts, :cereal, :milk)
    end
end
```

And the response is all nulls but something gets created:

```
{
    "id": 32,
    "recipe": null,
    "fruits": null,
    "nuts": null,
    "cereal": null,
    "milk": null,
    "created_at": "2014-09-29T06:11:39.874Z",
    "updated_at": "2014-09-29T06:11:39.874Z"
}
```

The log looks like:

```
Unpermitted parameters: recipe
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "onboardings" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-09-28 23:11:39.874650"], ["updated_at", "2014-09-28 23:11:39.874650"]]
   (2.1ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered onboardings/show.json.jbuilder (0.4ms)
Completed 201 Created in 126ms (Views: 5.5ms | ActiveRecord: 9.6ms)
```

Any direction is appreciated! Totally lost after looking through all relevant SO posts.

Answer (score 0):

The key of your POST data is `recipe`, but your `onboarding_params` is

`params.require(:onboarding)`

In order to do the strong params correctly I think that would need to be something like

`params.require(:recipe).permit(:recipe_id, :Category)`